# Getting ORA-12514, but we can connect via SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, jdbc, sqlplus

We are suddenly getting the error `ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor` in our application.

Googling this seems to suggest a couple of easy solutions (e.g. found [here](http://dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12514_tns_listener_does_not_currently_know_service_requested.htm)), but they don't work for us.

The perplexing thing is:

- We can connect via SSH to the *server* running our application, and..
- we can **connect with SQLPlus on that server**, ..
- using the *exact same* JDBC connection parameters as the app (we can get them from a log during application startup, so we are sure they are the same).

**Why could it be that we can connect to the DB with SQLPlus, but our app cannot?**

Here are the two methods to connect (JDBC and SQLPlus), both consistently anonymised:

**JDBC**

```
{
jdbcDriver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver,
jdbcUser=THE_USER,
jdbcPassword=THE_PASSWORD,
configurationVersion=1.0.14,
jdbcURL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=THE_HOST)(Port=THE_PORT))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=THE_SERVICE_NAME)))
}
```

**SQLPlus**

```
sqlplus THE_USER/'THE_PASSWORD@'"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=THE_HOST)(Port=THE_PORT))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=THE_SERVICE_NAME)))"
```

Comment: "using the exact same JDBC connection parameters" - SQL\*Plus doesn't use JDBC. Do you mean you're using Easy Connect; or are you supplying a TNS alias (@name or via TWO_TASK) and that alias is defined with the same values? Please edit your question to show exactly how you are connecting in both cases, and what `lsnrctl services` shows on the server  - preferably the real values, but if you have to change values for security then please make sure you do so consistently.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I added the two anonymised connections.

Comment: OK; assuming you've anonymised consistently and you don't just have a typo in one of your real values, if `the_host` is a name does it resolve to the same IP address in both places, and is it the same host/IP you ssh'd into?

Comment: @AlexPoole, `the_host` is a host name. I cannot say how it resolves from within the java code, but I'd assume it does so correctly (i.e. the same as from cmd line), otherwise I'd expect a different error. We cannot SSH into that (DB server), only into the application server (which is a different one).

Comment: What does the listener log say about the JDBC connection request - you should be able to see what service it's requesting (and if it's actually hitting the expected listener)

Comment: @AndrewSayer The logged JDBC request shows the correct service name, it is the same as used to connect using SQLPlus.

Comment: Compare the service name listed in the failed request in the listener log with the service names reported by 'lsnrctl status'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to our DB specialist there were "wrong entries in Oracle Internet Directory (OID)".

They cleaned it up and now it ist working again. Sorry that this is not very helpful as an answer, but I don't know more details...